# How to add no instrumentation attribute to printk in kernel?

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I am using `gcc` option `-finstrument-functions` to trace kernel functions. But I do not want to trace `printk` function. So I have used `__attribute__((no_instrument_function))` in `printk` definition in `kernel/printk.c`. But I still get the `printk` traces as `emit_log_char` in my result. Why it is not working? In printk.h they have it as `static inline __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2))) __cold int printk(const char *s, ...)`. How do I add the attribute there?

Comment: Maybe you can try this?

static inline __cold int printk(const char *s, ...)
__attribute__((no_instrument_function))
__attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)));